# Speed up the following queries by merging them into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find a way for merging two queries into one.

This is the structure of the tables I am using: 
(there are also other fields on contents and ratings but I didn't add them, since they aren't needed for this.

```
-- Create syntax for TABLE 'contents'
CREATE TABLE `contents` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `ratingsCount` int(8) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'ratings'
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `what` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rating` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Since last time I asked something here on stack overflow someone told me to write the code I'm using right now. Here it is:

```
db.query("SELECT AVG(rating) `avg`, COUNT(rating) cnt FROM `ratings` WHERE what = ?", [req.params.id], function(err, avg) {
    db.query("UPDATE contents SET `rating` = ?, `ratingsCount` = ? WHERE id = ?", [avg[0].avg, avg[0].cnt, req.params.id], function() { });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an UPDATE/JOIN combination to do it in a single round trip to the database;

```
UPDATE contents c 
JOIN (
  SELECT what, AVG(rating) rating, COUNT(rating) ratingsCount
  FROM ratings WHERE what = ? GROUP BY what
) r
  ON c.id = r.what
SET c.rating = r.rating, c.ratingsCount = r.ratingsCount
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26e08/1).

The subquery will find the average/count for the value of "what", the outer query will just join that information to update `contents`.

Comment: Note that subquery will use temporary table with consequent file sorting to do the join. If `ratings` table becomes large, performance be bad.

Comment: @ZaarHai You're correct, I updated the query to have the filter condition inside the subquery, that should help with the amount of data to join.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do the work:

```
UPDATE contents c SET
   rating=(SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings r WHERE r.what=c.id),
   ratingsCount=(SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM ratings r WHERE r.what=c.id);
```

You'll need to add index for `id` and `what` columns.